# Mqtt unsubscribe not ending topic subcription

Tags: node.js, mqtt

I am able to publish and subscribe to a topic but when the unsubscribe function is not working it?

```
var mqtt = require('mqtt');

var client  = mqtt.connect('mqtt://localhost:1883');
var topic = 'home/machine1/lightSensor';


client .on('connect', ()=>{
  client.unsubscribe(topic,console.log);
      });
```

it returning null

Comment: You've not shown enough code here for anybody to be able to help. unsubscribe should return null if there were no problems, but since you've not shown any of the code that subscribes or handles the message or actually described what happens after you unsubscribe we can't say any more.

Comment: How you understand that function is not working? if it return 'null' it mean there in no error.

Answer (score 1):

From the mqttjs [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mqtt#unsubscribe):

> **mqtt.Client#unsubscribe(topic/topic array, [options], [callback])**
>
> Unsubscribe from a topic or topics
>
> - topic is a String topic or an array of topics to unsubscribe from
> - options: options of unsubscribe.
>   properties: object
>
>   - userProperties: The User Property is allowed to appear multiple times to represent multiple name, value pairs object
> - callback - function (err), fired on unsuback. An error occurs if client is disconnecting.

Returning `null` is the correct response if the unsubscribe succeeds.